# Using the boids algorithm for multidirectional boids

Tags: algorithm, movement-prediction

I have some difficulties with my basic collision system in croweded places as it is based on simple box to box or radius detection. Sometimes characters are stuck to something or stopped because there is no way to go around. I'm trying to see if the boids algorithm can help, specifically using the separation behavior. In my simulation the boids are going in random directions. The problem I have is that boids are supposed to go in a similar direction. Indeed what I see is some boids moving the opposite of their direction to avoid others which is not nice.
So is it possible to modify the separation function to maintain the moving in the correct direction.

Alternatively maybe there is a better algorithm for that purpose.

Comment: Please post your code.  It is nearly impossible to debug from your description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have developped a small MFC dialog app to study the problem. Below is the code and a screen picture. What does this demo do:
It moves 20 boids in the limit of a 700x700 window with 3 ranbom obstacles in green.
boid 0 red and boid 1 blue have a target position to reach.
When a boid hit someting it turns according to its current direction and hit face. If there is no hit the boid try to recover its general direction (or target direction for b0 and b1). Putting too many boid makes the target search longer. 20 is fine.
I have adapted this to my regular project. A problem I see is when a character moves according to a defined path (AStar or predefined positions). Turning around other characters until no hit can led to the character moving too far from its current path and possibly loosing it. I currently managed this by some priority checking, e.g. character using a AStar check only obstacle, other character being in charge of avoinding the one using the Astar. Not the best but easy to mananged.

The code below test just boids, obstacles and window. No AStar or predefined positions.

```
typedef struct _BOID
{
DWORD   Index;//as in for loops counter
FLOAT3  Pos;
FLOAT   RotY;//general angle
FLOAT3  Dir;//general direction from general angle (random or to End)
FLOAT   Angle;//current angle
FLOAT3  Vel;//current direction from current angle
FLOAT3  End;//target pos if any
FLOAT3  Close;//accumulation parameter
RECT        Rect;//rectangle define by XZ volume on screen
BOOL        bStopped;//force stop if too many hits. optional
DWORD   Neighbor;//index of closest boid hit found otherwise 0xFFFFFFFF
DWORD   Count;//as in for loops counter
FLOAT   Turn;//amout of rotation if hit found
}BOIDS, *LPBOIDS;

// MaxBoid defines the number of boids we want (20 in the picture)
//RECT Obstacle [3] define the 3 random obstacles in green
// BOIDS B[MaxBoid] define moving boids
//On the picture boid0 (red) and boid1 (blue) want to reach their colored targets.

Void OnTimer()
{
    for (DWORD b1 = 0; b1 < MaxBoid; b1++)
    {
        LPBOIDS pB1 = &B[b1];
        CheckBoidToWorld(pB1);
        for (DWORD b2 = 0; b2 < 3; b2++)
        {
            CheckBoidToObstacle(pB1, &Obstacle[b2] ,45);
        }
        pB1->Angle += pB1->Turn;
        if (pB1->Turn == 0) //no obstacle and no window limit
        {
            //boids 0,1 want to reach a target 
            if (b1 < 2) ReorientToTarget(pB1);
            //other boids want to have a global direction
            else ReorientToGlobalDir(pB1);
        }
        else pB1->RotY = pB1->Angle;
        //update changes
        //to stay in the range [0..2PI]
        if (pB1->Angle < 0)pB1->Angle += PI2;
        if (pB1->Angle > PI2)pB1->Angle -= PI2;
        //could be x=sin and z=cos depending on left or righthand matrix.
        pB1->Vel.x = cosf(pB1->Angle);
        pB1->Vel.z = sinf(pB1->Angle);
        pB1->Close.x = pB1->Close.z = 0;
        pB1->Close.y = 1e6; //maxdistance in close.y to find closest boid
        pB1->Neighbor = 0xFFFFFFFF;//no closest neighbour at start
        pB1->Rect.top = pB1->Pos.z - 10;//update rect for moving boids
        pB1->Rect.left = pB1->Pos.x - 10;
        pB1->Rect.bottom = pB1->Pos.z + 10;
        pB1->Rect.right = pB1->Pos.x + 10;
        pB1->Count = 0;
        pB1->bStopped = false;
    }
    for (DWORD b1 = 0; b1 < MaxBoid; b1++)
    {
        LPBOIDS pB1 = &B[b1];
//the b2 loop can be optimized by b2=b1+1 to MaxBoid
//if the check is symmetrized from b1 to b2 and b2 to b1 in the     CheckBoidToBoid function
        for (DWORD b2 = 0; b2 < MaxBoid; b2++)
        if (b1 != b2)
        {
            CheckBoidToBoid(pB1, &B[b2]);//search closest one
        }
    }
//finalize the movement
    for (DWORD b1 = 0; b1 < MaxBoid; b1++)
    {
        LPBOIDS pB1 = &B[b1];
        if (pB1->Neighbor < 0xFFFFFFFF) UpdateBoidToBoid(pB1);
        pB1->Pos.x += pB1->Vel.x;
        pB1->Pos.z += pB1->Vel.z;
    }
}
Some modifiable parameters
FLOAT AvoidFactor = 0.02f;
FLOAT AreaClose = 40*40;//not necessary to sqrt the distance
FLOAT AreaFar = 100*100;
FLOAT MaxSpeed = 3.0f;
FLOAT MinSpeed = 1.0f;
FLOAT TurnBoid = 0.001f;
FLOAT TurnBloc = 0.1f;
FLOAT RotFactor = 0.1f;
FLOAT Speed = 0.5f;
//the window size is 700x700. I consider a limit=40 for starting to turn.
BOOL CheckBoidToWorld(LPBOIDS pB1)
{
    pB1->Turn = 0;
    FLOAT3* pP1 = &pB1->Pos;
    FLOAT3* pD1 = &pB1->Vel;
    FLOAT K;
    if (pP1->x < 40)
    { 
        K = 4-pP1->x/10;
        pB1->Turn = (pD1->z<0) ? TurnBloc*K : -TurnBloc*K;
    }
    if (pP1->x > 660)
    {
        K = 4 - (700 - pP1->x) / 10;
        pB1->Turn = (pD1->z>0) ? TurnBloc*K : -TurnBloc*K;
    }
    if (pP1->z < 40)
    {
        K = 4 - pP1->z / 10;
        pB1->Turn = (pD1->x>0) ? TurnBloc*K : -TurnBloc*K;
    }
    if (pP1->z > 660)
    {
        K = 4 - (700 - pP1->z) / 10;
        pB1->Turn = (pD1->x > 0) ? -TurnBloc*K : TurnBloc*K;
    }
    return pB1->Turn!=0;
}

Void CheckBoidToObstacle(LPBOIDS pB1, LPRECT pR, FLOAT Limit)
{
    FLOAT3* pP1 = &pB1->Pos;
    FLOAT3* pD1 = &pB1->Vel;
    FLOAT TurnZ = 0;
    FLOAT K = 0.99;
    if (pP1->x >= pR->left - Limit)
    if (pP1->x <= pR->right + Limit)
    if (pP1->z >= pR->top - Limit)
    if (pP1->z <= pR->bottom + Limit)
    {
        if ((pP1->x > pR->left - Limit) && (pP1->x < pR->left))
        {
            pB1->Turn = (pD1->z<0) ? -TurnBloc : TurnBloc;
            TurnZ = fabs(pD1->x);
        }
        else
        if ((pP1->x > pR->right) && (pP1->x < pR->right + Limit))
        {
            pB1->Turn = (pD1->z>0) ? -TurnBloc : TurnBloc;
            TurnZ = fabs(pD1->x);
        }
        else
        if ((pP1->z > pR->top - Limit) && (pP1->z < pR->top))
        {
            pB1->Turn = (pD1->x>0) ? -TurnBloc : TurnBloc;
            TurnZ = fabs(pD1->z);
        }
        else
        if ((pP1->z > pR->bottom) && (pP1->z < pR->bottom + Limit))
        {
            pB1->Turn = (pD1->x>0) ? TurnBloc : -TurnBloc;
            TurnZ = fabs(pD1->z);
        }
        //use TurnZ as an amplifier effect based on perpendicular direction 
        //to hit obstacle face. 0.25f is an arbiray non-zero value
        pB1->Turn *= 0.25f + TurnZ*0.9f;
    }
}

Void CheckBoidToBoid(LPBOIDS pB1, LPBOIDS pB2)
{
    FLOAT3 XZD;
    XZD.x = pB1->Pos.x - pB2->Pos.x;  XZD.z = pB1->Pos.z - pB2->Pos.z;
    XZD.y = XZD.x*XZD.x + XZD.z*XZD.z;
    if ((XZD.y < AreaClose) && (XZD.y < pB1->Close.y))
    {
        pB1->Neighbor = pB2->Index;
        pB1->Close = XZD;
        //can be stopped if too many neighbors
        pB1->Count++;
        if (pB1->Count > 2) pB1->bStopped = true;
    }
}

Void UpdateBoidToBoid(LPBOIDS pB1, INT Sign)
{
    if (pB1->bStopped)
    {
        pB1->Vel.x = 0;
        pB1->Vel.z = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        pB1->Vel.x += pB1->Close.x*AvoidFactor*Sign / pB1->Count;
        pB1->Vel.z += pB1->Close.z*AvoidFactor*Sign / pB1->Count;
    //normalize new velocity
        FLOAT DD = sqrt(pB1->Vel.x*pB1->Vel.x + pB1->Vel.z*pB1->Vel.z);
        if (DD > 0)
        {
            pB1->Vel.x /= DD;
            pB1->Vel.z /= DD;
        }
        pB1->Angle = atan2f(pB1->Vel.z, pB1->Vel.x);
    }
}

Void ReorientToTarget(LPBOIDS pB1)
{
    pB1->Dir.x = pB1->End.x - pB1->Pos.x;
    pB1->Dir.z = pB1->End.z - pB1->Pos.z;
    float NewRot = atan2f(pB1->Dir.z, pB1->Dir.x);
    float DRot = pB1->Angle - NewRot;
    if (fabs(DRot)  > PI) pB1->Angle += DRot*0.01f; else  pB1->Angle -= DRot*0.01f;
    pB1->RotY = pB1->Angle;
    pB1->Dir.x = cosf(pB1->Angle);
    pB1->Dir.z = sinf(pB1->Angle);
    pB1->Vel = pB1->Dir;
}

Void ReorientToGlobalDir(LPBOIDS pB1)
{
    float DRot = pB1->Angle - pB1->RotY;
    if (fabs(DRot)  > PI) pB1->Angle += DRot*0.01f; else  pB1->Angle -= DRot*0.01f;
    if (pB1->Turn != 0) pB1->RotY = pB1->Angle;
    pB1->Dir.x = cosf(pB1->Angle);
    pB1->Dir.z = sinf(pB1->Angle);
    pB1->Vel = pB1->Dir;
}
```

[image]

Comment: If this solved your problem, click the ✅ icon on the left to mark this answer as "Accepted".

Answer (score 0):

You can make the friendly forces weaker when the neighbor's alignment deviates enough from the target direction.

This essentially treats boids that go in the opposite direction as predators to avoid.